# Capture the same image in different resolutions - Camera2, Android

Tags: android, android-camera2

Do you know if it's possible to capture exactly the same frame in two different resolutions using the Camera2 API?

I want to capture an image at 1280x720 pixels and an other one at the maximum resolution accepted for the camera, and it has to be exactly the same image, it's not valid to capture one and just after that capture the other.

Thanks in advance! And I'm sorry if my English is not very good, I'm not an English speaker.

PD: I know that if it's not possible I can resize the high resolution image.

Comment: I think it is impossible, but as you've said - you can just resize larger image.

Comment: Have you tried using bitmap?

Comment: @UmarZaii Why should I use a bitmap?

Comment: Bitmap can resize images.

Comment: @UmarZaii Thanks! But I already knew how to resize an image, but it is my plan B.